# React counter not changing on the right interval

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, react-lifecycle

I am doing a small project with react lifecycles and I am attempting to change all box colors randomly every time the counter reaches a number divisible by 5 however, the boxes only change when the number is divisible by 10.

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Counter from "./components/Counter";
import Box from "./components/Box";

function App() {
    const randomColor = [
        "#0d0d8c",
        "#a41313",
        "#064826",
        "#996e00"
    ];

    const [number, setNumber] = React.useState(0);
    const [boxes, setBoxes] = React.useState([]);
    const [color, setColor] = React.useState('red');
    const [change, setChange] = React.useState(false);

    let box = boxes.map((obj, idx) =>
        <Box key={idx} color={color} />
    );

    let getColor = () => {
        if (boxes.length % 5 === 0) {
            let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomColor.length);
            setColor(randomColor[rand]);
            return randomColor[rand];
        }
        return color;
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (boxes.length % 5 === 0) {
            let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomColor.length);
            setColor(randomColor[rand]);
            return randomColor[rand];
        }
        return color;
    }, [color])

        React.useEffect(() => {
            if (number % 2 === 0) {
                let newBoxList = [...boxes];
                newBoxList.push({color: getColor()});
                setBoxes(newBoxList);
            }
        }, [number,change]);


        let reset = () => {
            setNumber(0);
            setBoxes([]);
            setChange(true);
        };

        return (
            <div className="App">
                <button onClick={() => setNumber(number + 1)}>Increase</button>
                <button onClick={reset}>reset</button>
                <Counter count={number}/>
                <div className="boxes">{box}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }

export default App;
```

deployed site: https://priceless-spence-9ae99a.netlify.app/

Comment: Were you able to get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I think the culprit is your `useEffect()` hook listening to `number`. Whenever `number` is even you are copying the existing contents of `boxes` and then *adding* new boxes to the existing boxes; you are not actually updating *all* boxes in the array. It seems your desire is to have all of those boxes, existing and new, be updated to a new color so you'll need to iterate through the array and update each.

I think it comes down to the fact that you are assigning the return value of `getColor` to your new boxes rather than the value of local state `color`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could move the tracking of color outside of `boxes` and instead reference it from local state whenever doing an in-line map of `boxes` in your return statement. That way every box is referencing the value in local state, you won't need to worry about updating each box!